# Does Google Cloud Dataprep support importing Google Drive Sheets as data sources?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep, trifacta

I'm importing datasets in Google Cloud Dataprep (by Trifacta) to perform transformations on my data sources. But I can't see Google Drive Sheets in the list after connecting them to Big Query Console. I'm about to use them as rules for my transformations.

I've already created another dataset and the problem persists.

Is it possible to import them or not supported yet?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Using-BigQuery_59736092#reading-from-tables-in-bigquery) Dataprep only supports native BigQuery tables and views as BigQuery sources.

You could try downloading your Drive sheets as csv and then creating a [BigQuery table from it](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#loading_data_from_a_local_data_source), or maybe you could create a [load job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language#top_of_page) from your external table into a new native table using:

```
SELECT * FROM my_dataset.my_external_table
```

Comment: I would add that OP could use a scheduled query to materialize and update your sheet data into a native table as well, which may be helpful if it will change frequently and he doesn't want a manual step in the process.

Comment: I used @justbeez's approach and it works beautifully - one addition: designating a Google Sheet as an external table can result in a lot of empty rows. I added a WHERE [field] IS NOT NULL to the scheduled query to prevent adding those to the native table.